# lag entire rows by zoo object in r

Tags: r, dplyr, lag, zoo

Consider the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df <- structure(list(FILIAL_CODE = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), 
    UNIDADES = c(26394, 24314, 26280, 25056, 28827, 24781), MES_ZOO = structure(c(2010, 
    2010.08333333333, 2010.16666666667, 2010.25, 2010.33333333333, 
    2010.41666666667), class = "yearmon"), PRODUCTOSUNICOS = c(3592L, 
    3337L, 3459L, 3256L, 3355L, 3196L), DEVOLUCIONES = c(39L, 
    22L, 12L, 24L, 26L, 31L)), .Names = c("FILIAL_CODE", "UNIDADES", 
"MES_ZOO", "PRODUCTOSUNICOS", "DEVOLUCIONES"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

> df
Source: local data frame [6 x 5]

  FILIAL_CODE UNIDADES  MES_ZOO PRODUCTOSUNICOS DEVOLUCIONES
1          10    26394 ene 2010            3592           39
2          10    24314 feb 2010            3337           22
3          10    26280 mar 2010            3459           12
4          10    25056 abr 2010            3256           24
5          10    28827 may 2010            3355           26
6          10    24781 jun 2010            3196           31
```

How do I lag entire rows of variables to create a new set of variables in the previous month.

For example, I would get:

```
newdf<-structure(list(FILIAL_CODE = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), UNIDADES = c(26394, 
24314, 26280, 25056, 28827, 24781), MES_ZOO = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 4L), .Label = c("abr 2010", "ene 2010", "feb 2010", 
"jun 2010", "mar 2010", "may 2010"), class = "factor"), PRODUCTOSUNICOS = c(3592, 
3337, 3459, 3256, 3355, 3196), DEVOLUCIONES = c(39, 22, 12, 24, 
26, 31), NEWMONTH = structure(c(2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 6L), .Label = c("abr 2010", 
"feb 2010", "jun 2010", "mar 2010", "may 2010", "NA"), class = "factor"), 
    NEW_PRODUCTOSUNICOS = structure(c(3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 6L), .Label = c("3196", 
    "3256", "3337", "3355", "3459", "NA"), class = "factor"), 
    NEW_DEVOLUCIONES = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("12", 
    "22", "24", "26", "31", "NA"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("FILIAL_CODE", 
"UNIDADES", "MES_ZOO", "PRODUCTOSUNICOS", "DEVOLUCIONES", "NEWMONTH", 
"NEW_PRODUCTOSUNICOS", "NEW_DEVOLUCIONES"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")

> newdf
  FILIAL_CODE UNIDADES  MES_ZOO PRODUCTOSUNICOS DEVOLUCIONES NEWMONTH NEW_PRODUCTOSUNICOS NEW_DEVOLUCIONES
1          10    26394 ene 2010            3592           39 feb 2010                3337               22
2          10    24314 feb 2010            3337           22 mar 2010                3459               12
3          10    26280 mar 2010            3459           12 abr 2010                3256               24
4          10    25056 abr 2010            3256           24 may 2010                3355               26
5          10    28827 may 2010            3355           26 jun 2010                3196               31
6          10    24781 jun 2010            3196           31       NA                  NA               NA
```

For added dificulty, I need to do this for every "FILIAL_CODE".

This is an example but there can be "n" of these FILIAL_CODE, each with "n" months. The months don't repeat inside of each "FILIAL_CODE".

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, we can do this after converting the 'MES_ZOO' column to `character` class as the `zoo` class is not supported within the `mutate` (using `dplyr_0.4.1.9000`).  We group by 'FILIAL_CODE', get the `lead` of columns MES_ZOO to DEVOLUCIONES using `mutate_each`, change the column names and `left_join` with the original dataset.

```
 df$MES_ZOO <- as.character(df$MES_ZOO)
 library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
     group_by(FILIAL_CODE) %>%
     mutate_each(funs(lead), MES_ZOO:DEVOLUCIONES)%>% 
     setNames(., c(names(.)[1:2], paste0('NEW_', nm1))) %>% 
     left_join(df, .)
```

---

Or we could use `shift` from the devel version of 'data.table' i.e. `v1.9.5` (Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`).  Specify the columns to `shift` in the `.SDcols`, use `shift` with option `type='lead'` grouped by 'FILIAL_CODE'.  Create new columns by assigning (`:=`)

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
nm1 <- colnames(df)[3:5]
setDT(df)[, paste0("NEW_", nm1) :=shift(.SD, type='lead') ,
                 by = FILIAL_CODE,  .SDcols = nm1]
df
#   FILIAL_CODE UNIDADES  MES_ZOO PRODUCTOSUNICOS DEVOLUCIONES NEW_MES_ZOO
#1:          10    26394 Jan 2010            3592           39    Feb 2010
#2:          10    24314 Feb 2010            3337           22    Mar 2010
#3:          10    26280 Mar 2010            3459           12    Apr 2010
#4:          10    25056 Apr 2010            3256           24    May 2010
#5:          10    28827 May 2010            3355           26    Jun 2010
#6:          10    24781 Jun 2010            3196           31        <NA>
#   NEW_PRODUCTOSUNICOS NEW_DEVOLUCIONES
#1:                3337               22
#2:                3459               12
#3:                3256               24
#4:                3355               26
#5:                3196               31
#6:                  NA               NA
```

Comment: When you make a character object out of the zoo column, the lag is arranging by name, thus the lag is not one month but one year...

Comment: @eflores89 Sorry, I didn't get your comment.  I get the same output as in the expected based on the iinput data for `dplyr`.  For the `data.table` solution, I didn't the convert the zoo column to character object.

Comment: sorry. The issue is this: I can't mutate a zoo obj (a bug with dplyr), so when I change to character and then lead the variable, I get a jump of a year (may 2010 -> leads to -> may 2011). In the example you don't have this issue because the names are not repeated (only 6 rows!)

Comment: @eflores89 Did you try the `data.table` solution (It didn't require zoo to character conversion)?  Also, please consider to provide an example that mimics the issue so that it would be easier to test.